# How do i display .pdf in browser (same window )?

Tags: css, html

When i click on hyper link "file1" it display file on new window, how do i get it on same window?

```
<div class="main-navigation">
  <ul class="navigation">

    <li><a href="#file1">File1</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
<!-- .main-navigation -->
<div class="page-section" id="file1">
  <div class="row"> <b>File1</b>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <object data="data/File1.pdf" `enter code here`type="application/pdf" width="500" height="500">
      </object>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a pure html solution, adding the target="_self" attribute to the anchor tag should work.

```
<li><a href="#file1" target="_self">File1</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: it renders to new page

Answer (score 0):

[Check here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) for the explained version on W3schools. I hope this explains it for you!

`target="_self"`, as answered by code9999, should work in your case.

*Sorry can't comment dont have enough reputation points ;)*